# no operator "=" matches these operands operand types are std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> = int

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm getting the error no operator "=" matches these operands operand types are std::basic_ostream> = int when running code in C++ and i'm not sure whats actually causing the error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    double average;

    // Input 2 integers
    cout << "Enter two integers separated by one or more spaces: ";
    cin >> num1, num2;

    //Find and display their average
    cout << average = (num1 + num2) / 2;

    cout << "\nThe average of these 2 numbers is " << average << "endl";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout << average = (num1 + num2) / 2;` probably doesn't do what you want. Check the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: `cin >> num1, num2;` also doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: `average = (num1 + num2) / 2;  cout << average;`

Comment: What's the `cout <<` doing there? You're displaying the average later.

Comment: Maxim's answer is correct also change `"endl"` to `endl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler treats

```
cout << average = (num1 + num2) / 2;
```

As:

```
(cout << average) = ((num1 + num2) / 2);
```

See [C++ operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) for more details.

Fix:

```
cout << (average = (num1 + num2) / 2);
```

Prefer simpler statements:

```
average = (num1 + num2) / 2;
cout << average;
```

---

Also

```
cin >> num1, num2;
```

Should be

```
cin >> num1 >> num2;
```

Comment: After making suggest changes I get  " error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'num2' used" I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: @TerrenceLong it means you use a variable before it has a value. `cin >> num1, num2` does not change `num2`